# What are industry standards and professional best practices in network hosts naming?

Tags: domain-name-system, hostname, best-practices, identity-management

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Naming convention for computers](https://serverfault.com/questions/161515/naming-convention-for-computers)

It seems an important and difficult dilemma for me how to name network hosts (routers, servers (while a server can be a router and host diverse services at the same time), virtual machines (while they host important services and can migrate), workstations and notebooks (using pc-username is not the best idea as users may change), printers & MFUs, surveillance IP cameras, etc).

Are there known and accepted best practices for this task?

Excuse me if there already was a similar question here (I think it probably was), I haven't found it.

Answer (score 2):

Only these as far as I know:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc952
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc273
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc236

Any other conventions are linked to particular limitations like for mainframes

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'industry standard' (naming convention) when it comes to naming network hosts.   There are plenty of ideas here:

**https://serverfault.com/search?q=naming+convention**