# Servers Hostname Normalisation

Tags: cloud, hostname, iso

I'm currently building a private servers farm with a thousand and thousand hosts, and I suddenly faced a really interesting question that I was unable to answer at the moment.

Is there a Standard ISO/Whatever for servers hostname attribution into a really large environnement?

For now, my puppet generate a random alphanumeric hostname that it not relevant for anyone connecting on the host.

That fine, and I'm able to connect to the correct server and service for maintenance because my puppet is managing all my host and link them to Nagios which has category etc.

But I'm really interesting to know if someone already faced this kind of question AND/OR if you have personal experience and testimony.

Many thanks!

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/161515/naming-convention-for-computers

Comment: http://serverfault.com/search?q=computer+naming+conventions

Comment: I don't think that the links answers to the question because it's mainly focus on PC Workstations where I'm rather focus on Server side, even if the RFC answer is something that I looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using a Proxmox cluster with a lot of container, and I use "technical" naming based on the container id, for example, container id 101 will give an hostname of `vm101.internal-domain.tld` and I try to map the private ip to the container id (actually I start from 1000 my id).

However, for long-lived container, I use a CNAME to describe and easily go back to it.

My naming convention is : 'generic to precise'.

Example:

My organization is named "acme", I've the `acme.net` domain.
I'm working a project named "`terminator`", I'll have `terminator.acme.net`, now, if for example my terminator project have differents service like frontends, mysql, etc.

I'll name them like these:

- `production.mysql.terminator.acme.net`
- `production.frontend01.terminator.acme.net`
- `staging.mysql.terminator.acme.net`

It works well for me.

So basically the pattern is `{environnement}.{service}.{project}.{company}.net`

Comment: I quit agree your nomenclature and I'll try to use it since I've got a single domain with many sub-organization.
So mark your nomenclature as the correct one.